# Prove that a language is in co-NP

Tags: complexity-theory, formal-languages

For a homework assignment, I have to prove that a given language $L \in coNP$.

I understand that one way of doing so, would be to prove that $\bar{L} \in NP$, i.e. give a polynomial time verifier for $\bar{L}$.

I am having trouble understanding what the complement of the language would be. eg: if

$$L = \{ (a, b, c) \in Z^{+}   |   \nexists \text{  } x \in Z^{+} \text{ s.t. } x < a \} $$

Then, is

$$\bar{L} = \{ (a, b, c) \in Z^{+}   |   \exists \text{  } x \in Z^{+} \text{ s.t. } x < a \} $$

Or is $\bar{L}$ a different language? Do I take the complement of the left hand side of the pipe operator? That is, can $\bar{L}$ contain strings from $Z^{-}$ now?

Comment: What is the *alphabet* your language is defined over? Is it, for example $\{0,1,\#,\}$? where we interpret $\#$ as a comma?
Once you fix the alphabet and the encoding of the language, it is easier to understand the complement.

Comment: I'm assuming that the language consists of triplets of the form (0, 3, 8) or (8, 11, 7) - basically made up of three positive integers. That's all the information the question had, though my example is a simplified version.

Answer (score 1):

Languages are defines with respect to a finite alphabet. Thus, integers cannot be represents just by giving a triplet as you suggest, you need to *encode* it.

For convenience, let's assume a decimal encoding, with the "$-$" sign for negation, and the character $\#$ separating the numbers. Thus, for example, the word $8\#12\#-3$ represents the triplet $(8,12,-3)$ (note that usually we would use a binary encoding, but it doesn't really matter). Call our alphabet $\Sigma$.

Now, a word $w$ is in the language you describe iff the following hold:

1. $w=a\#b\#c$ where $a,b,c$ are either words in {0,...,9}^*$\setminus {0}^*. That is, they represent positive numbers (we allow leading 0's here, but we could also formulate without them).
2. There does not exist $x\in \mathbb{Z}_+$ such that $x<a$.

Note that we did not do anything yet, just wrote down the language. In particular, we purposely ignore the fact that condition 2 simply means that $a\le 1$.

The formal complement of your language is the set of words that either don't satisfy condition 1, or don't satisfy condition 2 (or both).

You could write this more succinctly or more explicitly, as words that are either not of the form $a\#b\#c$ with the condition 1 above, or words that are of that form, but where $a$ is not of the form $0^*1$.

It should be mentioned that once you are familiar with the notion of languages, we usually don't dig down to this level of formality, and in fact we would ignore the encoding somewhat. Then, you might see things such as 
$\overline{L}=\{(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{Z}: \exists x\in \mathbb{Z}_+ \wedge x<a\}$.

Also note that throughout this answer we do not distinguish between a word and its numeric value, but if you really want to nitpick, then such a distinction should be made.

Comment: As long as membership in the domain of "well-formed triples" (or whatever we want out "real" domain to be) can be decided quickly, the difference between the "technical" and "real" complement should indeed by of no import to complexity.

Answer (score 0):

NP and co-NP are classes of problems where every instance of the problem has an answer that is either "yes" or "no".

A problem is in NP if for every instance where the answer is "yes", there is a hint that can be used to prove the answer is "yes" in polynomial time. (The hint can be extremely difficult to find, but you don't need to find it, you just need to show that if the answer is "yes" then such a hint exists).

A problem is in co-NP if for every instance where the answer is "no", there is a hint that can be used to prove the answer is "no" in polynomial time. (The hint can be extremely difficult to find, but you don't need to find it, you just need to show that if the answer is "no" then such a hint exists).

There are equivalent formulations: For NP: Whenever the answer is "yes", there is a proof that the answer is "yes" which can be checked in polynomial time. For co-NP: The same with "yes" replaced by "no".